# Dimension of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-rank

Is dimension of vector space spanned by a set of vectors the rank of the matrix ( vectors as columns) or its nullity.

Consider the vectors  $$\alpha_1=(1,1,0,1,0,0),\\
\alpha_2=(1,1,0,0,1,0),\\
\alpha_3=(1,1,0,0,0,1),\\
\alpha_4=(1,0,1,1,0,0),\\
\alpha_5=(1,0,1,0,1,0),\\
\alpha_6=(1,0,1,0,0,1).$$
The rank of the matrix obtained is 4. And hence it is said the dimension is 4. But I had always thought that the dimension is (no. of columns - rank).

Reducing to echelon form
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0& 0  & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0& 0 & 0& 0 & 0& 0\\
0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Evidently there are two free variables say $u,v$, therefore on writing the span, I got $span=u(-1,0,-1,-1,0,1),v(-1,-1,0,-1,1,0)$.

The span obtained is of dimension 2 and not 4. This is what confused me.

Comment: Note that the third component of the vectors tells us no linear combination of $\alpha_1,\,\alpha_2,\,\alpha_3$ can be $\alpha_4$.

Comment: Yes I get it. There are four linearly independent vectors and hence dimension of basis is 4. But what about the span I ve written above.

Answer (score 1):

Appeal to intuition: What if the vectors were all zero? What ought the dimension be? Is that the rank or the nullity of the corresponding matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The rank of a matrix is **defined** as the dimension of the vector space spanned by its columns. Its not a consequence but a definition.